# How do I fix these errors while trying start Virtual Box?

Tags: terminal, vagrant, virtualbox, centos7

I commanded 'vagrant up' on my terminal, to login my virtual CentoOS7 server then,I got these errors.

Just before I tried to up vagrant, I was customizing my vim editor on CentOS7 server on my vagrant. and then, I sat some important document.
maybe it caused this error...
and I found similar question on the web but I couldn't fix it.

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "6f113832-832d-4fd6-ba87-af003b3dddce", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Could not open the medium '/Users/yamadaasuma/VirtualBox VMs/MyCentOS_default_1551371079969_97354/centos-6.8-x86_64-disk001.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file '/Users/yamadaasuma/VirtualBox VMs/MyCentOS_default_1551371079969_97354/centos-6.8-x86_64-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
```

And these are the logs from my Virtual Box.
Please help me anyone.

```
00:00:00.040456 VirtualBox VM 6.0.12 r133076 darwin.amd64 (Sep  3 2019 12:00:40) release log
00:00:00.040456 Log opened 2019-09-20T13:35:04.466754000Z
00:00:00.040456 Build Type: release
00:00:00.040456 OS Product: Darwin
00:00:00.040456 OS Release: 18.6.0
00:00:00.040456 OS Version: Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64
00:00:00.040456 DMI Product Name: MacBookAir7,2
00:00:00.040456 DMI Product Version: 1.0
00:00:00.040456 Host RAM: 8192MB (8.0GB) total, 3483MB (3.4GB) available
00:00:00.040456 Executable: /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxHeadless
00:00:00.040456 Process ID: 64193
00:00:00.040456 Package type: DARWIN_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.043166 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:00.043208   None installed!
00:00:00.045230 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:00.050801 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:00.061957 Power up failed (vrc=VINF_SUCCESS, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is showing because vagrant cannot find the virtual box file which is associated with the project's virtual machine. Maybe it was deleted by accident.

In order to solve the issue open the Virtual Box GUI and then right click on the virtual box which is associated with the issue and click on `remove`.

This will delete the association from Virtual Box.

Now you can run `vagrant up --provision` and it will remake the box for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

`vagrant reload --provision`

then

`vagrant up`

This cheatsheet can you help you more. https://gist.github.com/wpscholar/a49594e2e2b918f4d0c4

Answer (score 0):

It should solve the problem

```
VBoxManage startvm "6f113832-832d-4fd6-ba87-af003b3dddce" --type headless
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try to run the following command in CMD as administrator:

```
sc start vboxdrv
```

According to this forum post: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9318

A complete reinstall of VirtualBox fixed the issue for some users.